# How to fix a Git malloc error (code 6: pointer being freed was not allocated)?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have run into a problem using Git today that has made me unable to do anything with my repository.

When opening the repo in SourceTree this dialog appears immediately:

[image: This is the error that appears using SourceTree]

I opened up Terminal and tried `git status` and I got this (which looks like the same error):

```
git(5986,0x7fff7933f300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd641d11160: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I finished working on the project yesterday and committed my changes. This worked fine but when I went commit new changes today the error above appeared.

Any ideas on what this is and how to fix it?

Searching the problem hasn't yielded any results as most of what I found were iOS related  questions. The project I am working on is an Android project using Android Studio.

Comment: The problem seems to come from git itself, which is a bit surprising. Are you sure you did not accidentally modify the git binaries on your machine? Can you do a `git --version` and provide the output? Which OS are you running on your dev computer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I haven't done anything to the binaries, not intentionally anyway. git version 2.0.1 on OS X 10.10.2

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall/reinstall git? If you have an md5 tool such as `md5sum` available, can you also provide a checksum of the git executable?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet. I was going to leave that until I had ruled out as much as possible. I might just do it and see.

Comment: I just tried to run `git add .` and it worked. I'm not sure what has happened here as the files I was working on were already in version control (committed, pushed, etc.).

Comment: If your git binaries haven't been corrupted, then it's a bug in git itself. You might try reinstalling git.

Comment: Reinstalled git. It's working fine but it was working just before I reinstalled so I'll just have to wait and see what happens. Thanks for your help _Buddyshot_ and _Keith Thompson_.